# Simple CURL redirect

Tags: redirect, curl

I have been around this site looking for solution to my question, some answers look close but not as much to find the solution to my issue
I have PHP curl to login to certain site and redirect to certain link while logged in.

```
***First to log:***
```

$ch = curl_init();

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https  >somesite');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'some other site');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 220);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).DS.'cookies.txt');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).DS.'cookies.txt');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'userid='.$log.'&password='.$pass.);
     $content = curl_exec( $ch )

***then run this to get away from page with ads *** 

     $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
     $fnd='ads'; ***// check to see if has ads***
     $pos=strpos($info, $fnd); 
    if ($pos!==false)
      {

$url1 = "https - link to redirect while logged id"; // ***I have this link for sure***
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
curl_setopt( $ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,100); 
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).DS.'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).DS.'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

$content = curl_exec ($ch1);
```

but that is not working.

Who would kindly answer me?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "not working"? For instance, do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard a dialog in a horror movie(not sure though) long time back "*Easy Pizzy, that means crazy*". Solution of your problem is easy, but not until you know it :-)

Close your curl to make sure it saves the cookies into the file. Otherwise its always empty and hence not working on second call.

```
// use it before second curl call
curl_close($ch);
```

In fact its always a good practice to close the curl instance after the needs are done!